# What is the limit of this sequence? Including a cosine

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let the sequence $(a_n)$ be defined by $$ a_n = \frac{ n + \cos(n)}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}}. $$ I need to find the limit of this. But since the cosine term will oscillate infinitely many times between $-1$ and $1$, how can the limit exist?

Answer (score 0):

The cosine oscillates but it is bounded. The denominator becomes arbitrarily large so it neutralizes the oscillating part of the numerator.

Write your limit as a sum of two individual limits and prove that the second limit is 0.

Comment: I see, thanks. But I don't understand why $\lim \frac{ \cos n}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints : Since $|\cos(n)|\le 1$, we have
$$ \left|a_n - \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\right| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}.$$

In addition, we know that
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}  \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} = \lim_{n\to +\infty}  \frac{n}{n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}}=\cdots $$